# How many positive integers values of n there such that $2^{2^{2020}}-1 $ divisible by $ 2^{2^{n}}+1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, divisibility

How many positive integers values of n there such that $2^{2^{2020}}-1 $ divisible by $ 2^{2^{n}}+1$.
I found think a piece of full solution is :

let,
$2^{(ab)}-1=(2^a-1)(1+2+2^2+..2^{((a-1)b))}$

Here $ab=2^{2020}.$

We can take $ a=2^n$ for $n≤2020.$
for such an even$ a , 2^n -1$ is divisible by$ (2^n/2)+1$

So for all $x ≤1010 $;

$2^x+1$ will divide $2^{(2020)}-1$

How to do the full solution.

Comment: $2^{2^{2020}}-1=(2^{2^{2019}}+1)(2^{2^{2019}}-1)=(2^{2^{2019}}+1)(2^{2^{2018}}+1)(2^{2^{2018}}-1)=\dots$ $=(2^{2^{2019}}+1)(2^{2^{2018}}+1)\dots(2^{2^2}+1)(2^{2}+1)(2+1)(2-1)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are $2019$ such values. Clearly $n>=2020$ won't work.

We prove that $2^{2^i}-1$ divides $2^{2^{2020}}-1$ for all $2\le i \le 2020$

the proof is by descent and boils down to $2^{2^i}-1=(2^{2^{i-1}}+1)(2^{2^{i-1}}-1)$

We can also use the expression $2^{2^i}-1=(2^{2^{i-1}}+1)(2^{2^{i-1}}-1)$

to notice $2^{2^i}+1$ divides $2^{2^{2020}}-1$ for all $1\leq i \leq 2019$